# Regex for string pattern such as Question1Label

Tags: regex

So I have a bunch of labels submitted from my view which can range from Question1Label to Question10Label. I would like to create a regex which can validate that it follows the following format.

Question

Number

Label

Does anyone know how to create a regex which can do this?

I have this so far:

```
^Question[0-20]Label*$
```

Comment: `Question[1-9][0-9]*Label`

Comment: @Loaf close but it is then required to have the 0-9

Comment: it's then required to have the second digit when it may only have one

Comment: I fixed it, changed to * instead of +

Comment: awesome mate, submit it as the answer and then ill select. Does the * mean optional?

Comment: Yea, + means at least 1, * means you can have none as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Question[1-9][0-9]*Label` will work for 1-99

If you want to just have 1-20 the following should work too:

`Question([1-9]|1[0-9]*|20)Label`

This basically means we have have 1-9 or a 1 followed by 0-9 or 20.